# Play Framework routing with multiple parameters

Tags: playframework

I'm trying to setup a SEO friendly route in the Play! Framework that has multiple parameters (with the 2nd parameter being optional).  What I'm aiming for is:

```
http://domain.com/article/jsmith/name-of-article
```

But what Play is generating is:

```
http://domain.com/article/jsmith?articleSlug=name-of-article
```

In my view:

`@{Article.show("jsmith","name-of-article")}`


**My Controller**

`public static void show(String username,String articleSlug){
...
}`


**My routes file**

```
GET /article/{username}                  Article.show
GET /article/{username}/{articleSlug}    Article.show
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems your template is matching with the first route. Reversing the order will do the trick,

```
GET /article/{username}/{articleSlug}    Article.show
GET /article/{username}                  Article.show
```

Also have your controller to accept username and articleSlug.

```
show(username, articleSlug){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved what you are looking for using the following mappings:

routes:

```
GET     /{<[0-9]+>id}/{slug}            Listing.show
GET     /{<[0-9]+>id}                   Listing.show
```

there must be **two** controller methods for this to work:

```
public static void show(Long id, String slug) { /* ... */ }
public static void show(Long id) { /* ... */ }
```

and then it can be used from a view:

```
#{a @Listing.show(item.id, item.title.slugify())}link title#{/a}
#{a @Listing.show(item.id)}link title#{/a}
```

Comment: maybe the item.title.slugify() is not interpreted for an unknown reason... did you try to create a variable before containing var slug = item.title.slugify() and then <a href="@{Listing.show(item.id, slug)}"> ?

Comment: your first template is taking your second route. For the second template, do you have a matching controller ie. show(id, slug) ?

Comment: Yes! That second controller method was missing. I was thinking is tolerant to this and just does not use the second parameter.